# how to modify child window DOM using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following "/tmp/d.html",

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var child = null;
$(function() {

  $("#buttonToOpenAnotherWindow").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    child = window.open('file:///tmp/a.html');

        $(child.document).ready(function(){

        //alert('child');
      $("body", child.document).append( 'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff');
        });
  });

});
</script>
  <a href="#openAnother" id="buttonToOpenAnotherWindow">Open Another Window</a>
```

(only showing the main parts)  my intention is to click the button, then it opens up another page , then I'll modify that child window page. when I tried this out on firefox 23.0 on linux, I do see the second window opened, its page showing "fffffffffffffffffffffffff", but then quickly the original content of "/tmp/a.html" replaced the page, and the "ffffffffffffffff" is gone. somehow if I put a debugger break before append(), it works as I intended.

my end goal for doing this is to fire up a child window, modify the child window with jquery so that it automatically clicks a button (to download one file from that page), then after the .ajax() download is completed, close the child window---- to do this I need to get a handle to the deferred obj returned by .ajax(), from the parent window. but one end blocker I may  run into is cross-domain: if I open another domain in child window, the parent window won't be able to modify its content. then I have to use greasemonkey in the child window, but then I won't be able to wait on the deferred obj from the child window, and close the window after download completion.

Thanks
Yang

---- update

after the onload() actually makes the child run, I ran into cross-domain issues, now I tried the following code from child window:

```
        $('body', window.opener.document).append('child child child');
        $('#closechild', window.opener.document).trigger('click');
```

weirdly, the first line worked, but the second doesn't. my intention was that the "#closechild" button in parent would call childwindow.close(). this button, when clicked in main window manually, does work. but it doesn't work when called from child window as above

Comment: same result using onload event of `child.window`?

Comment: ah, thanks, onload() works. but just I thought, now I run into the issue of cross-domain restriction. from the main /tmp/d.html I can open /tmp/a.html, but I can't open another domain ("http://www.yahoo.com" for example ) , actually firebug doesn't even give a permission error in console, just silently ignores my attempt to modify yahoo page DOM.

Comment: Fortunately, you cannot modify DOM from other origin, this is for obvious security reason... An alternative is to proxify it server side

Comment: what does "proxify" mean ? anyway I don't have a server here, just trying to automate my process by greasemonkey on top of some existing sites.

Comment: now I'm trying the route of window.opener.somethingsomething() and maybe some notify